# keep filters/sort status when changing page and go back

Tags: yii2

is it possible to keep the filters and sorting state when I go from a page with a GridView to another page and go back?
For example, if I have a page with a list (GridView) of items, after apply some filters/sorting the user may click on the item's "view" link, see the item's page and then go back to the list; in this case I want the filters/sorting to keep their status.

Comment: Easiest way I've found of doing this is to set the values as session variables in your Controller when it goes through to filter the GridView. From there, you can pass in the session variable to the model if it exists, and the GridView will be filtered straight away on load

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, if you are not using any `Ajax` or None-POST solutions, you probably know that all needed values are being passed through `GET` request.

So, these two methods might be useful:

**[Remember()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#remember()-detail)**

> Remembers the specified URL so that it can be later fetched back by previous().

**[previous()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#previous()-detail)**

> Returns the URL previously remembered.

So, you can `remember` a filter after each page or after each filter, then get the previous filters by using `previous()`